# bash formula for sed to remove value in strings

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

i need formula for sed because i have many files with many strings inside, i must remove 10 character in the middle of string and then go other string

```
primi-ordini-per-te-apri-questo-annuncio-leggilo-bene-chiamami-infernetto-it1a1fx8m/index.html" target="_self" ref="title">>redincontri<
```

i need formula for sed to remove `-it???????`

i use `grep` with `|` for pass the strings to `sed` and then `> print file`

i tried with sed with this formula

```
|  sed "s/-it*//"
```

but no result

i have mac osx with brew and xcode installed update

thanks

Comment: The question is not clear at all

Comment: `echo 'primi-ordini-per-te-apri-questo-annuncio-leggilo-bene-chiamami-infernetto-it1a1fx8m/index.html" target="_self" ref="title">>redincontri<' | sed 's_-it[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]__g'` will give you primi-ordini-per-te-apri-questo-annuncio-leggilo-bene-chiamami-infernetto/index.html" target="_self" ref="title">>redincontri<. You can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `-it*` should be `-it.*`. You're confusing wildcards with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Using any sed:

```
$ echo 'primi-ordini-per-te-apri-questo-annuncio-leggilo-bene-chiamami-infernetto-it1a1fx8m/index.html" target="_self" ref="title">>redincontri<' |
    sed 's:-it[^/]*::'
primi-ordini-per-te-apri-questo-annuncio-leggilo-bene-chiamami-infernetto/index.html" target="_self" ref="title">>redincontri<
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove precisely ten characters, starting with `-it`, the command should be:

```
| sed 's/-it.\{7\}//'
```

This matches the `-it` then 7 repetitions of `.`.

`.` matches any single character.

`\{7\}` is an interval specifier. See section 5 of [BREs Matching Multiple Characters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06) in the POSIX Regular Expressions specification.

---

In the command shown in your question, `-it*` matches `-i` followed by zero or more occurrences of `t`. Note that this will not give "no result", it will give the wrong result.